# How to turn Lubuntu back to Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I wanted to try out the Ubuntu flavor Lubuntu. I don't like it and I want to change it back. I've tried multiple things to delete Lubuntu and reinstall Ubuntu. One of them being using the commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge lubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Neither has worked. I got a result telling me that 0 things happened and 22 things were not upgraded.

Comment: It's apt-get remove not apt-get autoremove.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove lubuntu-desktop from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453841/how-to-remove-lubuntu-desktop-from-ubuntu-14-04-lts)