# can we update ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04 which is of another ubuntu flavor?

Tags: upgrade, updates

I've installed Ubuntu mate 14.04 5 days ago and now i want to shift back on Lubuntu.instead of downloading entire lubuntu 16.04 lts,can i just upgrade my Ubuntu mate to lubuntu as both are Ubuntu with different desktops?if yes then how?or should i just download lubutnu 16.04, which is better?

Comment: Do a clean install of Lubuntu. If you just upgrade, you'll upgrade to Ubuntu Mate. There's no way to switch flavors while upgrading that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just upgrade to 16.04 and then change your desktop manager.
    `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`
should do the trick to install LXDE. You can remove MATE by
    `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mate-desktop`

Comment: That will only remove the metapackage, not all the software installed by the metapackage.

Comment: @RecursiveCursive i do not want to this cause it broke my system twice

Comment: @SmitPatil could you describe how it broke your system? I have switched from Kubuntu to cinnamon twice and I have not faced any issues.

Comment: see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/908223/laptop-boots-like-lubuntu-when-i-installed-lxde-and-lubuntu-desktop-environment   also could you please post that how did you switch dektop safely?

Comment: @DKBose how about `apt-get remove mate-*`. Most of the software should be removed.

Comment: Such broad commands may have unintended consequences. If you want to go down that road, it's better to first run a simulation. Then, if you understand that all the packages can be removed safely, go ahead!

Comment: @SmitPatil you can have more than one desktop environment installed. Whenever you want to switch you just have to log out and click on the DE icon near the login. For more detailed info with screenshots, try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments

Comment: @DKBose agreed! --simulate should help you recognise what is being removed. But I would first suggest that the asker familiarises themselves with Ubuntu and then try out various DEs and removing them.

Comment: What OP wants to do is to upgrade Ubuntu Mate 14.04 to Lubuntu 16.04. In my opinion, that's not possible.

Comment: I thought OP wanted to preserve files and move to 16.04 with LXDE, but it looks like he wants a single step upgrade. I don't think that's possible either.